# How to implemenet Google Maps URL?

Tags: android, maps

I am trying to implemenet `routes` into my `Android` app. The way it should work, it's that a person behind a web page sets a route, and the user receives it on his phone. I thought that I could use a DB, to store the routes and then fetch them on my app. I found that I could use `Google Maps URL` to create a `URL` that has the origin, the destination and every waypoint I want. Web-wise, I managed to do all the coding behind so the operator can create the desired `URL` with the `route`, and I was thinking about storing the `URL` into a database. My question is, if I fetch the `URL` from the server on my app, is there any way to draw the `polylines` according to it? Or to show it in any other way? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can draw fetched routes on your map.

There is a tutorial here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/polygon-tutorial

If you want to use third party library for it. You should check github.

Answer (score 1):

if your link on this format

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&path=40.737102,-73.990318|40.749825,-73.987963|40.752946,-73.987384|40.755823,-73.986397&sensor=false
```

you can get the points to draw the polyline.

Comment: This is a sample, with 5 stops `https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=44.48710684274103,26.10757383814561&waypoints=%7C44.435673457153136,26.04682294670539%7C44.43646481126194,26.038947981037666%7C44.43726687871328,26.05083553139167%7C44.4348888210366,26.049749085973158%7C44.42898015242528,26.030310335408952&destination=44.43519015265054,26.04821980206537`

Comment: yes good then you can get this points by splitting the link for example `waypoints=` and `destination=` get this points and follow the [GUIDE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/polygon-tutorial) to draw it on your application

Comment: on the link `%7C` means `|`

Comment: Thanks! I've found the meaning of special characters. I thought about splitting the `url`, but asked here if there was other way around it. I will try with this solution!